# Query on Datalog Least Fixpoint Evaluation

Tags: model, logic, datalog

Can someone help me with this? Is the following statement true?

> If a least fixpoint evaluation of a datalog program does not terminate, then the least model must be infinite

My Answer:

> Yes, it is True, as in cases of function, the least fixpoint evaluation would not terminate.

Thank you